# Abantecart Template Customixation

Tags: php, smarty, opencart

I'm new to abantecart, How to integrate theme into abantecart. I hvae HTML files only. Please share any tutorial about it.

As I go to change default theme or create new extension which one is best.

Answer (score 1):

There were some instruction in below forum:
http://forum.abantecart.com/index.php/topic,1340.0.html

There is a dev guide here as well. 
http://www.abantecart.com/document_wiki/index.php/Developing_Templates_as_Extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest version of developer tools https://github.com/abantecart/developer_tools_extension. Just choose version for your AbanteCart, then download it into your "extension" directory, install and enable. After that go to admin menu system->settings->appearance and click "clone template" button.
It will copy default template (theme) as extension. You can change anything you want in it and be sure that upgrade of AbanteCart will not affect your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In admin menu system->settings->appearance "clone template" is not available..How to find this.

Comment: it available there only for Abantecart versions 1.2.0 and higher

Comment: you must install `developer_tools_extension` beforce clone theme